# How can I play Doom using Doom Engine on a Mac?

Tags: macos, doom

I saw recently that [John Romero tweeted](http://t.co/8vcFH4r4ND) that the best modern way to play Doom is to download the Doomsday Engine. I did this for my Mac, but it doesn't come with the WAD Files, which are required to play the game. I did an online search and it seems that these aren't freely available, but I can't find a MAC Version of the game for purchase.

If I buy the Windows or Linux versions of Doom, will the WADs therein be compatible with the Doomsday Engine for Macintosh? If so, how can I extract just the WAD files from the installer, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the game never came out for Mac directly. But, the WAD files are compressed files with the game data. They are delivered with any version of the game and actually x-platform. Therefore, it does not matter if you buy the game for windows or not.

You can either use the original Doom WAD or the one coming with the BFG Edition of Doom 3. 
Both will work with Doom Engine. If you use the WAD from the BFG Edition, you need to tell Doom Engine that you are using Ultimate Doom though.

If you want to run your original Doom, you can use DosBOX, which is available for MAC, Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I purchase it on Steam, even though it says for Windows only, I'll be able to able extract the WADs and use them with the Doomsday Engine on a Mac?

Comment: @DoomDoomDoom The WAD's don't need to be extracted, they just sit in the directory when you download the game. They are also delivered with the BFG Edition of Doom 3. I don't know if that works though. If you give me an hour I'll test it.

Comment: @DoomDoomDoom I tried the WAD from the BFG Edition and it works with Doom Engine. Was very painless to set up and ran out of the box. I updated my answer and I will edit your question to make it more on topic.

Comment: I bought the original Doom collection, but have no option to download the source files on OSX. The only related option in the context menu in my Library is `Install Game…` (which I can't, because my platform isn't supported). Did either of you manage to get Steam to provide you with the source, @Assylum, @DoomDoomDoom?